# Howto install a python app and add it to path in Linux?

Tags: linux, command-line, python

I've created a python app with several sub modules.
What's the prefered way to install/deploy such a multifile python app?
Any user and process should be able to call the app/script without changing into the app's directory.
I've placed the app in /usr/shared/myPyApp and created a link in /usr/bin to the main-script
But when I call it, the python-app doesn't find it's submodules. I think this happens because the workingdir is the path of the link.

1. create a bash script, set the working dir, start the python script and pass the cmd arguments
2. modifiy the python app ?
3. or?

Comment: Does it work OK if called explicitly (`/usr/shared/myPyApp/script.py`)?

Comment: Yes, it works if I call it with an absolute or relative path

Answer (score 0):

The easiest thing would be to simply add the directory where you have the script installed to your path. Add this line to your `~/.bashrc` file:

```
export PATH=$PATH:/usr/shared/myPyApp/script.py
```

You should then be able to run it by typing `script.py`.